# Look for various substrings and return the position of the one found

Tags: javascript

I want to analize a string for a substring and return the position of the substring if it was found.

```
function analize(t) {
    if (t.indexOf(" a ") > -1 || t.indexOf(" b ") > -1 || t.indexOf(" c ") > -1) {
        alert(t.indexOf(" a "));
        }
```

The problem is that I'm looking for more than one substring and I cant echo its position since I don't know which was found. While this example only has 3 strings, I need to do it with a lot more in my code. How can I check for various items and return the position of the one that's found?

Comment: What do you want it to do if multiple matches are found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression with [String.search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbc7a78k%28VS.94%29.aspx):

```
var position = t.search(/ a | b | c /);
```

This is easy enough to code up if your list of strings is constant.  But if your list is dynamic, you'd have to build the regular expression programmatically.  You can do so like this:

```
var searchStrings = [" a ", " b ", " c "].map(function (item) {
    return item.replace(/[*+?^$.\[\]{}()|\\\/]/g, "\\$&"); // escape RegEx meta chars
});
var position = t.search(new RegExp(searchStrings.join("|")));
```

Note that I used [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) above.  This will not work by default in older browsers.  You have to add it in manually.  See the [compatibility notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility) for an implementation you can use to get this functionality in older browsers.

Comment: If it *is* constant, ` [abc] ` or ` (a|b|c)` might be less repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to return the position of the first match:

```
function indexOfAny(strs, s) {
    for (var i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
        var ind = s.indexOf(strs[i]);
        if (ind != -1)
            return ind;
    }
    return -1;
}

indexOfAny(["a", "b", "c"], "test-b-stri-c-ng");
```

Returns:

```
5
```

Comment: For `"test-c-stri-b-ng"`, it returns 12, even though the first match is at position 5.

Comment: Yeah, I meant first match in the array. You could obviously do it the other way, too.

Answer (score -3):

just put the strings you look for in an array then use the for-in loop to go through each one and output the position if found.

```
function analyze(t) {
   var strings = ["a","b","c"...];
   for(index in strings]) 
      if(t.indexOf(string[index]) > -1) 
         alert(t.indexOf(" a "));
}
```

Comment: What gilly3 said. Also braces are your friend.